# Script to run multiple OpenCv programs in Windows

Tags: batch-file

I like to run several OpenCV programs one by one in a DO Loop. After searching the web , think for this case need to use batch file. Is that right?

I have 10 OpenCV programs. Each program detect specific features in the image with some successful rate. So, for any image(with many features to be detected) I wonna run first the program with the highest successful rate. If this failed to detect feature then run next one with second highest rate and so on. So, for example program1 is the one with the highest rate, then come program2 and so on

So I have output for each of the 10 OpenCv programs. Let we say output 1 if detect the feature (or the object) in the image and 0 if it failed. So the script should start the program 1 first and if the outcome of this program is 1 then will do something (not important at the moment what), but if the outcome is 0 then need to start the program 2. Same for program 2. If the output of program 2 is 1 then do something (also not important what), but if the output is 0 (means did not detect the object) then run the next program (means program3)

Any idea how it should look like?

I have  thinking of something like this , but not sure about the control

```
  @ECHO OFF
    START program1.exe
    ECHO Timeout waiting for program1.exe to start
    GOTO :EOF

      :: if the output of program1.exe is 1 then do somethig, else if the   output of program1.exe is 0 run the program2.exe (I dont know how this part should be in the script)

      :: not sure for control
    :startnext
    program2.exe
    :: or START program2.exe
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know the exit status of the last run command ?

Comment: aah no. Sorry , then can delete exit. I wonna know the exactly code for the  script . So how to run this several OpenCv programs sequentially , so start the next one after finished the previous one

Comment: How many programs do you have? You can iterate over your program executable names ( stored in a list ) and run them one after the other

Comment: Remove the `start` command. Without it the normal behaviour in batch files is to wait for the invoked process to end.

Comment: I have 10 OpenCV programs.  Each program detect specific features in the image with some successful rate. So, for any image(with many features to be detected)  I wonna run first the program with the highest successful  rate. If this failed to detect feature then run next one with second highest rate and so on.  Is this clear? so for example program is the one with the highest rate, then come program2 and so on

Comment: So I have output for each of the 10 OpenCv programs. Let we say output 1 if detect the feature (or the object) in the image and 0 if it failed. So the script should start the program 1 first and if the outcome of this program is 1 then will do something (not important at the moment what)., but if the outcome is 0 then need to start the program 2. Same for program 2. If the output of program 2 is 1 then do something (also not important what), but if the output is 0 (means did not detect the object) then run the next program (means program3)